# XHR request response text has unexpected character set

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, encoding, xmlhttprequest

I was looking at the answer, by @OmegaStripes, to this question [How to get a particular InnerText from a specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538472/how-to-get-a-particular-innertext-from-a-specific-class/41538937#41538937) Here one uses the `Split` function, and a specified delimiter string, to extract an `href` from `.responseBody`.

I then tried to replicate this to extract the following `href` :

```
"https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/02/New-AmbSYS-to-2018-Jan.csv"
```

from [NHS England's Ambulance Quality Indicators](https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/ambulance-quality-indicators/)

**HTML snippet:**

```html
<main class="main group" role="main">
        <div class="page-content" id="main-content">
            <header>
                <h1>Ambulance Quality Indicators</h1>
            </header>
            <article class="rich-text">
               <p></p>
              <p></p>
              <p></p>
               <p></p>
              <p></p>
              <p><strong>CSV Data</strong><br>
These files have the same data as other published spreadsheets, but without any formatting:<br>
                <a href="https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/02/New-AmbSYS-to-2018-Jan.csv" class="csv-link" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Downloads', 'CSV', 'https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/02/New-AmbSYS-to-2018-Jan.csv');">New Systems Indicators August 2017 to January 2018 (CSV, 23KB)</a><br>
            </article>
    </div>
</main>
```

**Problem:**

I am getting response text back that looks as follows:

**Example response text:**

[image: Response Text]

From a quick bit of research, see references, I am **guessing** this is perhaps an encoding problem?

I tried setting a `.SetRequestHeader`

```
 .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", _
     "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
```

This made no difference to the output.

To be honest, I haven't a clue how to resolve this.

Any suggestions please on how I get the expected response text? i.e. that I can parse for the `href` of interest.

**Context:**

This is part of a bigger piece of work where:

1. I want to scrape that CSV link (the name of which will change each month), **without** having the browser pop-up
2. Download the target file content
3. Use ADODB.Stream to write the binary file out.

This process was outlined by @OmegaStripes in response to my question [Return focus to ThisWorkbook.Activesheet after XMLHTTP60 file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525027/return-focus-to-thisworkbook-activesheet-after-xmlhttp60-file-download?noredirect=1#comment84053438_48525027) . I am trying to understand and implement that suggestion currently.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const url As String = "https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/ambulance-quality-indicators/"
Public aBody As String

Sub Testing()

    ' Download via XHR
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
        .send
        ' Get binary response content
        aBody = .responseBody
         
    End With
 
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = aBody

End Sub
```

References:

1. [XMLHTTP and Special Characters (eg, accents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100229/xmlhttp-and-special-characters-eg-accents)
2. [setRequestHeader Method (IXMLHTTPRequest)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms766589%28v=vs.85%29)
3. [VBA HTML Scraping - '.innertext' from complex table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781715/vba-html-scraping-innertext-from-complex-table/35782811#35782811)
4. [Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP and UTF-8 charset issues](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24114504/Msxml2-ServerXMLHTTP-and-UTF-8-charset-issues.html)

Comment: The response headers don't specify the encoding, which is probably why `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` is not properly decoding the body. Use an`ADODB.Stream` with `stream.CharSet = "UTF-8"`. For an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624736/convert-binary-to-string/26625611#26625611

Comment: @FlorentB. Thanks. I will have a look. I don't know if my ignorance but this seems to be for a later stage. Would this somehow link with the response text? I first have to identify the file url from the XHR.

Comment: be aware that `.responseBody` returns an array of bytes encoded as UTF-8. You are casting it to a `String` (`UTF-16` encoding) which is why you are getting all these foreign characters. If the CSV file contains only ASCII characters, then use `.responseText`, and if not, use `ADODB.Stream` to convert the `.responseBody`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So credit goes to @FlorentB for this solution and a shout out to @OmegaStripes for the suggestion.

As suggested, the problem indeed was the `.responseBody` was returning an array of bytes encoded as UTF-8. As pointed out, I was casting it to a String (UTF-16 encoding) hence all these foreign characters.

I used @Tomalak's function [`BytesToString`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624736/convert-binary-to-string/26625611#26625611), with minor changes, to handle the conversion to string.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const url As String = "https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/ambulance-quality-indicators/"
Public aBody As String 'this is causing the conversion
Const adTypeBinary As Byte = 1
Const adTypeText As Byte = 2
Const adModeReadWrite As Byte = 3
Public Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\testXMLHTTPOutput"

Public Sub Testing() 
    ' Download via XHR
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        ' Get binary response content
        aBody = BytesToString(.responseBody, "UTF-8")

    End With

    Dim fso As Object  'late binding
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oFile As Object
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strPath)
    oFile.WriteLine aBody
    oFile.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing

End Sub
'ADODB.Stream with stream.CharSet = "UTF-8"
'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx


Public Function BytesToString(ByVal bytes As Variant, ByVal charset As String) As String

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Mode = adModeReadWrite
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write bytes
        .Position = 0
        .Type = adTypeText
        .charset = charset
        BytesToString = .ReadText
    End With
End Function
```

Useful other link here:

[Save text file UTF-8 encoded with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524703/save-text-file-utf-8-encoded-with-vba)